# Apache Kafka: Consumer group duplication

Tags: apache-kafka

I was wondering if there is a quick way to duplicate a Kafka consumer group.
 Let say there is a consumer group: `test_cosnumer_group_a` and I want another consumer group `test_consumer_group_b` with the same properties (topics, offsets etc)

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information on how you're running your consumers and how you're initializing the KafkaConsumer object. What you're asking is a fundamental concept in Kafka. You just simply start your consumers with a unique group.id value and you read from the same topic. Offsets will be managed independently between the two consumer groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`kafka-utils`](https://github.com/Yelp/kafka-utils) in order to copy the metadata of a particular consumer group into a new one. According to the [docs on GitHub](https://github.com/Yelp/kafka-utils/blob/master/docs/source/kafka_consumer_manager.rst#copying-or-renaming-consumer-group),

> Consumer groups can have metadata copied into a new group using the
>   `copy_group` subcommand.
>
> `$ kafka-consumer-manager --cluster-type=test copy_group my_group1 my_group2`

Answer (score 5):

If using [confluent's scripts](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#ak-consumer-group-command-tool) you'll have `kafka-consumer-groups` instead of `kafka-consumer-manager`.

You can export offsets from a consumer group to a csv file and then restore it to another consumer group:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups \
  --bootstrap-server $KAFKA \
  --export --group $FROM_GROUP_NAME --topic $TOPIC \
  --reset-offsets --to-current \
  --dry-run > offsets.txt

bin/kafka-consumer-groups \
  --bootstrap-server $KAFKA \
  --execute --group $TO_GROUP_NAME \
  --reset-offsets --from-file offsets.txt
```

Credits to another SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57423974/2004857

Comment: this seems to require unfortunately that the second group exists already. A solution when the group should be created with the command?